# Yii2 get app web url without index.php

Tags: yii2

My Yii2 app is located at:

```
http://www.example.com/myYiiApp/
```

I want to get that URL from anywhere in my app. But using this:

```
Url::home(true)
```

Returns

```
http://www.example.com/myYiiApp/index.php
```

Is there are Yii command to return the url without index.php?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to configure 'urlManager' in 'components' in config/main.php

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
],
```

Take care that .htaccess is configured in web folder:

```
RewriteEngine on

# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: I don't need to access the app without index.php... i need to return a variable within the app. I can strip it with PHP but thought there would be a Yii command to return it.

Answer (score 0):

Barring a Yii direct command, I will use `dirname(Url::home(true))`